# Ripple-emulator on node.js

Tags: cordova, ripple

I've installed ripple-emulator on node shell (window 7) by  :

```
npm install ripple-emulator
```

but when I try to recall it appear error :

```
ripple is not recognised as internal command
```

It seems strange 'cause it is present in folder.

Comment: You forgot the global flag. It should be `npm install -g ripple-emulator`

Comment: Yes.Thank you. Now the browser open ripple but appears an alert  with:gap:["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager1671388621"] and the browser crash@AndrewLively